# Why is @Required ignored by Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I've read that @Required uses to make sure the property has been set.
But when I try to use it along with Spring Annotation Configuration it doesn't work.

Below you can familiarize with my code base.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean(initMethod = "initMethod")
    public SimpleClass simpleClass(){
        return new SimpleClass();
    }

}

public class SimpleClass implements InitializingBean {

    private int n;

    public SimpleClass() {
        System.out.println("constructor");
    }

    public int getN() {
        return n;
    }

    @Required
    public void setN(int n) {
        System.out.println("setter");
        this.n = n;
    }

    void initMethod(){

    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("afterPropertiesSet()");
    }

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        SimpleClass simpleClass = context.getBean(SimpleClass.class);

    }

}
```

Why does Spring application context create the SimpleClass Bean and don't complain about the absence of injection via setter?

UPD:
When I try to do the same using XML configuration and add  then I receive a "Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Property 'n' is required for bean 'simple'"

Comment: validation annotation are not Silver Bullet. In many context have only iformational role. I hope are really implemented in JEE containers for injected beans

Comment: @chrylis It is but it is an old.

Comment: Generally speaking, dependencies that are mandatory should be injected as constructor arguments, and only optional dependencies should be injected through setters.

Comment: @chrylis I agree totally about constructor injections. According to the actual code, the OP seems starting with Spring.

Comment: @davidxxx That's why I commented here instead of on your answer, since getting a general idea of the principles of how injection relates to Java objects in general is important starting out.

Comment: OP, also note that if you're writing a CLI program (with a `main`), you're usually better off using Spring Boot, which has lots of helpful support.

Comment: Could you give me a hint, how can I do it using Java Config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`@Required`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Required.html) documentation states (emphasis is mine) :

> Marks a method (typically a JavaBean setter method) as being
>   'required': that is, **the setter method must be configured to be
>   dependency-injected with a value.**

With Spring in order to configure a method as dependency injected you have to specify it (`@Autowired` is the standard way).

But specifying both `@Autowired` and `@Required` on a method seems clumsy today :

```
@Autowired
@Required
public void setN(int n) {
    System.out.println("setter");
    this.n = n;
}
```

Instead, to configure the setter to be both dependency-injected and required I advise to use only `@Autowired` that by default is required as you can notice :

```
public @interface Autowired {

    /**
     * Declares whether the annotated dependency is required.
     * <p>Defaults to {@code true}.
     */
    boolean required() default true;

}
```

So it is enough :

```
@Autowired    
public void setN(int n) {
    System.out.println("setter");
    this.n = n;
}
```

---

As a side note, the setter injection will probably fail as the `int n` will probably not be resolved as a dependency. The `@Value` annotation on the parameter could probably help you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use it along with @Autowired (or @Value if you inject simple values) annotation.

Comment: but why is it possible to use in XML Spring Configuration?

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by "use in XML configuration"?

Comment: When I try to do the same using XML configuration and add then I receive a "Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Property 'n' is required for bean 'simple'"

Comment: That's because you already autowire in your XML configuration, while you do not in your Java configuration.

Comment: How can I do it in Java Config?

Comment: By adding `@Autowired` or `@Value`

Answer (score 0):

Referring to this [article](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-core/spring-required-annotation-and-requiredannotationbeanpostprocessor-example/):

Without a `RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` bean, Spring will not complain.

So ... add another bean of type `RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` (using `@Autowired`) to make it complain.

Also, `@Required` annotation is to be used for Bean setter. You are trying to do `@Required` check on a primitive type. As far as I understand, all Spring Beans (or J2EE beans) are to be objects.

For primitive types, you can use a `@Value` injection.